# XML, combine 2 data sources

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

This may be a stupid questions. But i am wondering about how i can combine different data sources in xml.

Eksempel; I want to make a site where you can search name of a city. Then a combine of a Map informasion and Weather informasion would come up. Im not looking for a code. Just what do i need to make this.

Comment: Any code you have tried with? Paste it here

Comment: No im not looking for help to make it. But what would  i need to make that kind of site.

Comment: Same as any web site, main thing is to define what data your working with,  define the information you need and how it's linked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you process your data with XSLT, it's easy enough to read both the primary input of the transformation and secondary inputs; secondary inputs can be read using the document() function or the doc() function (or if they are non-XML data the unparsed-text() function.  In XQuery it's easy enough to have database collections of information about cities, maps, and weather, and refer to them from a query, using the collection() function.

So:  read up on document(), doc(), and collection(), collect some sample data, and start to build the site!  When you run into trouble, you'll be able to ask more concrete questions here and get help.  (As you will have noticed already from the close votes, very broad questions of the kind you have posed are frowned upon; they are not felt to be a good match for the question/answer format of the site.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).)